# Database field containing HTML display raw text

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

ASP.Net MVC3 using c#

I currently have a database field in my application that stores HTML but when I try to display the HTML field using.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.game_description)
```

Currently the HTML is being displayed as plain text how do I get it to render the HTML properly?

Comment: Basically what you need is to put HTML output as is and not be converted to DOM elements. If you have such a coding forum, you can use some Html sanitizer to make sure that you're not poisoning your DB content with potential XSS attack codes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean without HTML encoding it? You could use the `Html.Raw` helper:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.game_description)
```

And be warned and fully aware about the consequences of doing this: your site becomes vulnerable to [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). So make sure you know the origin of this HTML.

Comment: Alternatively declare your model property as `IHtmlString`.

Comment: Thanks worked great plus I am going to implement AntiXSS to remove the vulnerability http://wpl.codeplex.com/