# MVC3 display raw html with database first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have read several topics (like this one: [Database field containing HTML display raw text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635310/database-field-containing-html-display-raw-text)) but somehow can't find the solution.

I have this line:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Content) // this works, but shows unparsed html
```

But this does not work:

```
@Html.Raw(model.Content)
```

I get an `The name 'model' does not exist in the current context` error.
Since I used database first. I generated my model from the `*.edmx` file. So `Content` is of type `String`.

thanks in advance!

ps. my first non-webform project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `Model` rather than `model`:

```
 @Html.Raw(Model.Content)
```

When using `@Html.DisplayFor` the model is automatically passed in and given the name you assigned to it, in this case model.

Comment: Thanks! (have to wait 7 minutes before I can accept your anwser)

Comment: ps. why does visual studio generate every property with this linq?